# Finding The General Term Of A Sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Let there be a sequence $1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,...$ find the general term of the sequence

I manage to find a general terms for the elements in the even and odd places, but did find a connection: 

$a_{even}=\frac{n}{2}$, $a_{odd}=\frac{n+1}{2}$

Comment: Edited typo in my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are familiar with the floor function, aren't you?

How about $$a_n = \left \lfloor \frac{n+1}{2} \right \rfloor $$

Answer (score 4):

Build the differences:
$$\begin{array}{l}
{a_2} - {a_1} = 0 = \frac{{{{( - 1)}^1} + 1}}{2}\\
{a_3} - {a_2} = 1 = \frac{{{{( - 1)}^2} + 1}}{2}\\
{a_4} - {a_3} = 0 = \frac{{{{( - 1)}^3} + 1}}{2}\\
{a_5} - {a_4} = 1 = \frac{{{{( - 1)}^4} + 1}}{2}\\
 \vdots \\
{a_n} - {a_{n - 1}} = \frac{{{{( - 1)}^{n - 1}} + 1}}{2}
\end{array}$$
and add them:
$${a_n} - {a_1} =  \sum\limits_{k = 1}^{n - 1} {\frac{{{{( - 1)}^{k}} + 1}}{2}} $$
That is:
$${a_n} = 1 + \sum\limits_{k = 1}^{n - 1} {\frac{{{{( - 1)}^{k}} + 1}}{2}} $$
Because:
$$1 + \sum\limits_{k = 1}^{n - 1} {\frac{{{{( - 1)}^{k}} + 1}}{2}}  = \frac{1}{4}\left( {2n - {{( - 1)}^{n}} +1} \right)$$
we have:
$${a_n} = \frac{1}{4}\left( {2n - {{( - 1)}^{n}} +1} \right)$$
Voila!

Comment: for n=1 I get $\frac{1}{4}(2+1-3)=0$

Comment: @gbox: Your right. Edited once more. Must work now. Thank you.